# brew services start mongodb-community

Tags: mongodb, homebrew

I am trying to run MongoDB by running `brew services start mongodb-community`.  It showed Python cannot be opened because of a problem.  Can you please help me how deal with this problem.
It showed Python cannot be opened because of a problem. It ask me to check with developer to make sure Python works with this version of macOS.

[image]